# Are airline-related questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions related to the airline operations/procedures on topic? For example:

- fleet management
- crew management
- business practices (overbooking, expensive one-way tickets, etc.)
- etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would say fleet management, and to some extent crew management (related to duty times, rest requirements, etc. rather than [HR/Personnel stuff](http://workplace.stackexchange.com)) are certainly on-topic here.

Along the same lines, airline-scale maintenance stuff is certainly on topic (progressive inspection procedures and the like), as well as what goes into assembling the corporate flight manuals and procedures that part 121 carriers use.

The "business practices" bits I'm less certain about -- that's starting to get into economics and business as opposed to aviation. (For example, why some number-cruncher in the front office decided a one-way ticket from NY to Orlando is \$500, but a round-trip  between the same two airports is only $89 each way doesn't have anything to do with aviation - except that the ticket is for getting on a plane. One could ask a similar question about Amtrak fares.)

Answer (score 11):

Some overlap may occur with http://travel.stackexchange.com, but I would say yes. A huge part of the aviation industry revolves around airlines, and it seems like a relevant topic to allow.